# bluetooth GPS device in J2ME emulator / Wireless Toolkit

Tags: bluetooth, gps, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I'm developing a j2me application for my mobile phone (a Nokia). I'm using WTK (Wireless Toolkit) to test my code. 
Because I'm using a GPS device via a Bluetooth connection, I would like to be able to extend the emulator with bluetooth possibilities. Has anyone experience with BT & WTK?

according to [this article](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/bluetooth_gps/part1/) there is no way to do it by default. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulators "emulate" bluetooth, by allowing you to make a connection between running emulators using the bluetooth API.

I've never tried to convince an emulator to use actual bluetooth on a PC (however I suspect it may be just possible on the Sony Ericsson emulator using some hacking of where the Bluetooth API points to, would be a lot of work though).

Easier approach: if you're emulating a bluetooth GPS, write a MIDlet which acts as a Bluetooth serial server, and preload it with a bunch of NMEA data from your GPS unit.  Get the MIDlet spitting that out continuously on a loop.

Run that MIDlet, then get your real app to connect to that MIDlet (using emulated bluetooth) and consume the NMEA data as if it were coming from a real GPS -- bingo!

HTH